# Unable to create a new project in xcode using swift 5.4 (macOS 11.4 Big Sur)

Tags: xcode

I tried to change the swift version 5.4 but unable to change it. how can I change please help me?

[image: please check it]

Answer (score 1):

It happens by default, you don't need to switch to `Swift 5.4` manually. When it's in `Swift 5` mode, it is different according to different Xcode versions.

[swiftversion.net](https://swiftversion.net/) is a very useful resource for checking this.
[image]

Comment: by the way, I am using Xcode 12.5 so It should show the latest swift version.

Comment: No, on the UI part, it will still show `Swift 5`, but internally use `Swift 5.4`. As long as you are on `Xcode 12.5` and it shows `Swift 5`, then you are using `Swift 5.4` as you expect.